# Understanding of static_cast in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how `static_cast` works. I have the following code:

```
Projcet::ProjcetType result =
            static_cast<Projcet*>(DS)->removeProjcet(ID);
```

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) I learn that its used to create a temporary object.
How should the following command look like without `static_cast`? I feel like it will make me better understand what does it do.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention: `void *DS` and `Projcet` is a class.

Comment: What are `DS` and `Projcet`?

Comment: please se my edit

Comment: "*its used to create a temporary object*" - where did you get that from? Your link says it "*Converts between types using a combination of implicit and user-defined conversions.*"

Comment: why is DS `void*` ?

Comment: @melpomene I guess OP is referring to the "*Returns a value of type new_type.*" in the Syntax section or to "*(...) returns the imaginary variable (...)*" part.

Comment: @Thomas does it matter? The OP wants to know what `static_cast` does here, not how to make the code better

Comment: This static cast does indeed create a temporary object, of type `Projcet*`, a pointer to `Projcet`. It does not create an object of `Projcet` type, if that's what you are concerned about.

Comment: My question is how to do it without `static_cast`?

Comment: @JustSid it might matter if it's not really a `Projcet*`

Comment: @Thomas `static_cast` doesn't care if it's really a `Project` type or some random pointer. It'll just work and cast the pointer no questions asked.

Comment: @JustSid I was thinking more about the OP than the compiler. He might wan't to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @vesii You'd have to use some other type of cast, e.g. the old C-style `(Projcet *)DS` cast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that `DS` comes from some old windows lib that returns a `void*`. Probably written in C. So you get this void pointer and want to use it as `Projcet` reference. You compiler doesn't know anything about `DS` other than that it is a pointer. So it can not treat it like an object pointer of `Projcet`.

So by using `static_cast`, you tell the comiler that you want to use `DS` as a pointer to a `Projcet` object. Now the compiler can connect to the likes of the member `removeProjcet()`.

The downside of `static_cast` is that if you don't really have a pointer to a `Projcet` the program is most likely to crash. Worse, continue with undefined behavior.

Comment: is it possible to replace it though?